# jquery dialog popup shown in the same window

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I dont know whats wrong.
I follow this link http://www.dotnetcodesg.com/Article/UploadFile/2/286/CRUD%20operation%20using%20Modal%20Popup%20in%20ASP.NET%20MVC%204.aspx because need pretty same thing: CRUD grid with popup for edit.

I do everything inside HomeController and Index.cshtml which generated by VS2013.

I cut from the code the things involved:

Index.cshtml

```
 grid.Column("", header: "Actions",
                format: @<text>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditConstruct", new { id = item.Id, @class = "editDialog" })

<div id="dialog-edit" style="display: none">
```

Controller

```
 public ActionResult EditConstruct(int id)
    {
        var data = advConstructRepository.Get(id);

        AdvConstructModel model = new AdvConstructModel
        {
            Id = data.Id,
            Description = data.Description,
            MaintenanceTime = data.MaintenanceTime,
            Location = data.Location,
            Height = data.Height,
            Width = data.Width,
            MonthlyCost = data.MonthlyCost,
            AdvConstructType = advConstructRepository.GetAdvConstructType(data.AdvTypeId)
        };

        ViewBag.IsUpdate = true;
        return View("EditConstruct", model);
    }
```

Edit View

```
@model AdvApplication.Models.AdvConstructModel
@{
Layout = null;
}
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateConstruct", "Home", "POST"))
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        ViewBag.IsUpdate = true;
        return View("EditConstruct", model);
    }
 etc...
```

But when i clicked on Edit action, i receive fields for edit but not in the popup, but on whole screen as a single page.
EditConstruct view was created as partial view.

Please suggest how to fix

Answer (score 0):

It is probably the whole view being sent back, jquery deals in fragments, not whole pages.

Consider this change:

```
public ActionResult EditConstruct(int id)
{
    var data = advConstructRepository.Get(id);

    AdvConstructModel model = new AdvConstructModel
    {
        Id = data.Id,
        Description = data.Description,
        MaintenanceTime = data.MaintenanceTime,
        Location = data.Location,
        Height = data.Height,
        Width = data.Width,
        MonthlyCost = data.MonthlyCost,
        AdvConstructType = advConstructRepository.GetAdvConstructType(data.AdvTypeId)
    };

    ViewBag.IsUpdate = true;
    if(Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        return PartialView("EditConstruct", model);

    return View("EditConstruct", model);
}
```